# Missing default "appsettings.json" file in .NET Core WebAplication project

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to do a web application using Asp.Net Core but I realized don't have the appsettings.json by default file like this project.

[image]

Currently, my project is like this:

[image]

I need the appsettings.json to put the ConnectionString of the database.

So someone knows why I don't have the appsettings.json file by default? and How I can create this file?
another question is what is the appsettings.Development.json file in the first image?

My Program.cs is this

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually add a JSON file named appsettings.json to the project's root folder. The template appsettings.json is like this:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "ConnectionName": "your connection string"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can provide multiple setting files for each environment. For example, when you are running your app in the development environment you can set a connections string for the development database. The naming convention for appsettings.json file is **appsettings.Environment.json**.

Comment: but I see the "appsettings.Enviroment.json" is a sub-file of "appsettings.json" file. How i can do that sub-file?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio shows them as a group of settings. But they are simple and independent files as you can see using a file explorer. So create 2 separate files: "appsettings.json" and "appsettings.Development.json" in the project folder and include them in the project. The result will be as you expect.

Comment: thanks man, you save my sad saturday! 
last question: I need create "appsettings.Production.json" file?

Comment: No, appsettings.json applies to all environments. But if you are using an environment-based appsettings.Environemnt.json, it's settings will override appsettings.json in that specific environment.